# connect to solana and make transsection with flutter

Tags: web3.js, phantom, flutter

I want to create solana wallet so im learning how to do . i tried so many time to implement function but i cant . please write this function.  help me .

when some one click sent sol button, it will sent 0.01 sol to a specific address,  via connected address. so im unable to write  _sendSol() this function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:solana_wallet_adapter/solana_wallet_adapter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Solana App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

// 1. Create instance of [SolanaWalletAdapter].
final adapter = SolanaWalletAdapter(
  const AppIdentity(),
  // NOTE: CONNECT THE WALLET APPLICATION
  //       TO THE SAME NETWORK.
  cluster: Cluster.devnet,
);

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Object? _output;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Solana App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // 2. Authorize application with wallet.
                adapter
                    .authorize()
                    .then((result) => setState(() => _output = result.toJson()))
                    .catchError((error) => setState(() => _output = error));
              },
              child: const Text('Connect Wallet'),
            ),
            if (_output != null) Text(_output.toString()),
            const SizedBox(height: 20), // Add some spacing between buttons
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _sendSol,
              child: const Text('Send 0.01 SOL'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _sendSol() async {}







\n
// I want to create solana wallet so im learning how to do . i tried so many time to implement function but i cant . please write this function.  help me .
when some one click sent sol button, it will sent 0.01 sol to a specific address,  via connected address. so im unable to write  _sendSol() this function
}
```

Comment: using code blocks will help make this question more clear. it's hard to see what is code and what is your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i edited please help me now